# How to use FlatList to render heterogenous data in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I have two types of data one is a list of Transactions and the other are some details of the User. Since these are different types of data. How do I render them inside the same FlatList?

**Sample transactionData = [{amount: 200, date: '2020-08=02', desc: 'bill'}, {amount: 200, date: '2020-08=02', desc: 'bill'}]**

**Sample userData = {name: 'John Doe', gender: 'Male'}**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write render item function to deal with it

```
const renderItem = ({item})=>{
  if(//checkIfType1){
    return(<Type1Component data={item} />)
  }
  return(<Type2Component data={item}/>)
}
```

and use that function in renderItem attribute

```
renderItem={renderItem}
```

Comment: In order to render both in the same FlatList, you'll need to merge them both in a single array, assuming that is not already the case. Then, in your renderItem, you can conditionally render like in the answer provided by Muhammed. To check for type of data, you can use `if(item.amount)` to tell if it's a user data or not.